# Apache2 virtual hosts not working for SSL config

Tags: apache-http-server, ssl, https, virtual-host

I've had this virtual host setup on HTTP where different domains would serve files from different locations. This is my `000-default.conf` file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    <Directory /var/www/html>
       Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
       AllowOverride All
       Require all granted
    </Directory>
    
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/root
    
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    <Directory /var/www/html>
       Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
       AllowOverride All
       Require all granted
    </Directory>
    ServerName nature.sentenceman.com

    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/nature

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    <Directory /var/www/html>
       Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
       AllowOverride All
       Require all granted
    </Directory>
    ServerName games.sentenceman.com

    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/games

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    <Directory /var/www/html>
       Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
       AllowOverride All
       Require all granted
    </Directory>
    ServerName katiebenson.co.uk

    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/katie

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

This works fine, as you can see here:

- http://sentenceman.com
- http://nature.sentenceman.com
- http://katiebenson.co.uk

I then realised that when accessing them via HTTPS, all would just serve the root files, which was because I hadn't replicated these virtual hosts in my `000-default-le-ssl.conf` file. However, I've now done that, and it still doesn't seem to work, as you can see if you try to access any of the above over HTTPS:

- https://sentenceman.com
- https://nature.sentenceman.com
- https://katiebenson.co.uk

This is what this config file looks like:

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>

    <VirtualHost *:443>
        <Directory /var/www/html>
           Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
           AllowOverride All
           Require all granted
        </Directory>

        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html/root

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

        ServerName sentenceman.com
        Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
        SSLEngine on
        SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/sentenceman.com/fullchain.pem
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/sentenceman.com/privkey.pem
    </VirtualHost>

    <VirtualHost *:443>
        <Directory /var/www/html>
           Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
           AllowOverride All
           Require all granted
        </Directory>

        ServerName nature.sentenceman.com
        Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
        SSLEngine on
        SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/sentenceman.com/fullchain.pem
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/sentenceman.com/privkey.pem

        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html/nature

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    </VirtualHost>

    <VirtualHost *:433>
        <Directory /var/www/html>
           Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
           AllowOverride All
           Require all granted
        </Directory>

        ServerName games.sentenceman.com
        Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
        SSLEngine on
        SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/sentenceman.com/fullchain.pem
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/sentenceman.com/privkey.pem

        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html/games

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    </VirtualHost>

    <VirtualHost *:433>
        <Directory /var/www/html>
           Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
           AllowOverride All
           Require all granted
        </Directory>
        ServerName katiebenson.co.uk
        Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
        SSLEngine on
        SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/sentenceman.com/fullchain.pem
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/sentenceman.com/privkey.pem

        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html/katie

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    </VirtualHost>

</IfModule>
```

I've checked that it is enabled (I guess otherwise I shouldn't get anyhting on `HTTPS://`). Can anyone see anything wrong with this setup?

**Edit:** After fixing the wrong port mentioned in the accepted answer https://katiebenson.com now works! :D The other two don't and the apache error log told me why:

```
[Sat Jul 25 17:54:11.755069 2020] [ssl:warn] [pid 27351] AH01909: games.sentenceman.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches
the server name
[Sat Jul 25 17:54:11.755432 2020] [ssl:warn] [pid 27351] AH01909: nature.sentenceman.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches
 the server name
```

The certificates aren't wildcard certificates (that's next on my todo to create wildcard ones instead).

Comment: Check how the configs are being interpreted by running this command `apache2ctl -S` (Or perhaps `apachectl -S` or `httpd -S`) and you should pretty much see right away which configs are being used and in which order.

Comment: Also check that your default host does not have some kind of catch-all like `ServerAlias *` configured

Comment: [This answer](https://superuser.com/a/1571588/167207) is the answer: Two of your configs are set for the incorrect HTTPS port `433` and not the correct `443` HTTPS port.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your HTTPS VirtualHosts for `katiebenson.co.uk` and `games.sentenceman.com` are defined for port 433. The actual HTTPS port is 443.

Comment: Doh! Captain Obvious to the rescue.

Comment: Doh! That was an embarrasing one!